# Excel VBA loop for deleting a range when a cell has a 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA loop in which the loop checks the cells in column M and if it finds a zero, it will delete the range "ii:Mi". I'm not that familiar with for loops so I thought I could get help here.

The code I came up with is as follows but I think it's missing something or it's too simple for the action:

```
Sub delete()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To 100

If Mi = 0 Then
Range("Ii:Mi").Select
Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for the answers, they're very much appreciated.

Comment: When you say `"ii:Mi"` what do you mean exactly? Something like `M2:M15`? and if you are going to delete the cell, it's way much easier doing it from last to first.

Comment: There are many issues with this code. Could you share the screenshots of your worksheet before and after (desired)?

Comment: As stated above, your pseudo code is difficult to be understood... At least, do you want deleting the range "I2:M2" if "M" is 0? I mean **deleting the respective cells**  (the ones below coming up), clearing their content or delete the whole respective (`i`) row?

Comment: I was referring to the range consisting of columns I to M, i.e for row 3 I3:M3.  And I only wanted to delete that range, not the entire column as it's not possible as I have a Pivot table next to the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your goal, this should work. Thought it will clearly mess your data using the Delete function:

```
Option Explicit
Sub delete()
    
    'Change the "SheetName" for the actual sheet name
    'Assuming that sheet is in the same workbook as the code
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
        'Try to find the last row with data instead going
        'arbitrary 3 to 100
        Dim last_row As Long
        'this gets the last cell with data in column M, change as needed
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        'Store all the rows meeting your criteria in a single variable
        Dim range_to_delete As Range
        'loop through the column
        Dim C As Range
        For Each C In .Range("M3:M" & last_row)
            If C.Value = 0 Then
                If range_to_delete Is Nothing Then
                    Set range_to_delete = .Range("I" & C.Row, "M" & C.Row)
                Else
                    Set range_to_delete = Union(range_to_delete, .Range("I" & C.Row, "M" & C.Row))
                End If
            End If
        Next C
    End With
    
    'Lastly, delete the cells meeting your criteria.
    'Thought this will mess up your data big time since you are deleting row 2 from column I to M
    'so the data in row 3 from column I to M will now be in row 2.
    If Not range_to_delete Is Nothing Then range_to_delete.delete xlUp
    
    'If instead, you just want to clear the cells change:
    'range_to_delete.delete xlUp
    'for:
    'range_to_delete.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code, it worked exactly like I wanted. And glad that you mentioned the possible problem of messing up the data, but my data is of the kind that I won't be encountering it (as I only possibly have values of zero at the end or middle of the range).